# Create a link to acces a local file outside "wwwroot" directory in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

how can i access to a local file outsite wwwroot in coldfusion. I want to do a "href" link to access a file outside wwwroot directory. I tried many different solutions but any of them worked.

Comment: What are some of those solutions you tried? There's a good chance any answers you get are going to use those same techniques.

Comment: Is the file html or some sort of binary, like jpg, mp3, etc?

Answer (score 6):

You can't link to a file outside of your web root, that helps keep your server safe. However, if your CF server has permission to access that other folder, you can write a CF page in your application that can present a file from that folder using `CFCONTENT`.

HOWEVER, do NOT try to access that file by passing a path to that file in the query string. That opens you up to other security issues. Create a table in the DB that maps those files to a File ID, then make sure that your logged in user has the correct role or privilege to access the file.

You'd create a file `getFile.cfm` and pass `id=123` in the query string. Once you verify that your user can access the file in question, use this code to present it to the browser:

```
<cfheader name="Content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=#dafile#">
<cfcontent file="#dafile#" type="application/pdf">
```

Just make sure that the `type` attribute contains the correct [mime-type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) for the file in question.

*This example is from [Ray Camden's post](http://ray.camdenfamily.com/2006/3/10/Ask-a-Jedi-Using-ColdFusion-to-serve-files) on the subject.*

Comment: Note how he has that configured - passsing a key like "id=123". Don't do something like pass the file name for example. If you do, someone will start passing things like filename=../../../../boot.ini or whatever and get acces to virtually any file they can dream up. Also emember taht part of your "getfile.cfm" file should check to see if the user has appropriate permissions to be viewing the file - otherwise, nefarious users start passing other ids to see if they can view other files (if you see what I mean). Security should be your FIRST issue when accessing files outside of the web root.