# how can I use cfdirectory to make a list of documents downloadable using ColdFusion/Lucee?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

In my Application.cfc, I setup a mapping

```
this.mappings["/downloads"]="J:\Downloads\documents";
```

In my template, I have

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#expandpath("/downloads")#" filter="*.zip|*.docx" name="downloads" recurse="yes">
<!--- <cfdump var="#expandpath("/software")#"> --->
<cfdump var="#downloads#">
<ul>
    <cfoutput query="#downloads#">
        <li><a href="#downloads.directory#/#downloads.name#">#downloads.name#</a></li>
    </cfoutput>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make the documents downloadable but when the link is clicked, nothing is happening which makes me think my links are not correct however when I mouse over the link, I see the full path which is correct.

What am I missing to make the list of documents clickable?

[image]

Here is the URL displayed when mouseover the 3rd document for example.

[image]

Comment: The files are outside of the webroot if that makes a difference.

Comment: Since the files are outside of the webroot you will need to create a page in CF that will accept the path of the file you want to download, read it into memory, and then stream it to the client.

Comment: I moved the files to within the webroot and having the same issue, nothing happens when the filename is clicked.

Comment: Now that the files are in the webroot what does the url look like?

Comment: file:////c:/user/hpwd/websites/siteabc/downloads/new rich text document - copy.docx

Comment: I changed my source code to `<li><a href="#downloads.directory#/#downloads.name#">#downloads.name#</a></li>` and now the link is clickable and the file downloads as expected. So the issue how to make the files appear as a download when they are outside of the root.

Comment: I found this very similar topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282978/create-a-link-to-acces-a-local-file-outside-wwwroot-directory-in-coldfusion. I thought there was a way to include other folders as if they belonged to the web site but maybe I'm confusing IIS virtual directories with Coldfusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the files are outside of your webroot you will need to have ColdFusion read the file and send it back to the browser.

You will need to create a page, like download.cfm, that can accept a URL parameter to know which file to access. Once you have selected the file you can use something like the following to stream the file.

```
<cfheader name="Content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=#datafile#">
<cfcontent file="#datafile#" type="application/pdf">
```

The above code was pulled from https://www.raymondcamden.com/2006/03/10/Ask-a-Jedi-Using-ColdFusion-to-serve-files

**WARNING:**
Reading URL parameters in this way and giving people access to the filesystem is extremely unsafe. Safer alternatives should be considered before moving something like this into a production environment.

Comment: Agree with the approach using `<cfcontent>`. You 100% DO NOT want to put the file path in the query string. Find some way to use a UUID or numeric ID to reference which file to load. You'll also want to validate the user is logged in (if required) before downloading the file.

Comment: If you're concerned about "which user should have access to which file", that will require a lookup table, security-wise.  Like Adrian said above, assigning an ID of some sort will allow a user to ONLY retrieve a file listed in the ID/UUID lookup list.  You don't want someone getting access to system files simply because they know the path.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno - I'm always glad when I see your name, I value your input. Since you "signed off" on the cfcontent approach, I'll pursue this solution further.

Comment: @WillBelden - I understand what you are saying about security, thanks. This might be a tangent but isn't there a way to setup a virtual directory (not sure if that's the right term here) in such a way that it isn't the actual physical path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282978/create-a-link-to-acces-a-local-file-outside-wwwroot-directory-in-coldfusion

Comment: @HPWD You should consider <cfcontent> if you really want to make it secure.  Yes, you could use a virtual directory, in conjunction with your webserver, but in the end, if you had  https://example.com/files/a.txt and b.txt, any web user could attempt to create filenames until they come up with a retrieval.  Using a fileId and <cfcontent> would prevent one user from retrieving another user's or other not-for-them file.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do for *this* exercise is to setup a mapping in my Application.cfc. As others have stated, there is zero security here but for the purpose of this exercise of understanding virtual directories (IIS) and aliases (CommandBox), this is sufficient.

`this.mappings["/guides"]="J:\guides";`

Then I can use cfdirectory to build my query object

`<cfdirectory action="list" directory="j:\guides" recurse="false" name="nameofqry" type="file" sort="datelastmodified desc" filter="*.docx">`

Next, perform a cfoutput using my alias as the a href link

```
<cfoutput query="nameofqry" maxrows="40">
    <li><a href="/guides/#nameofqry.name#" class="downloadlink" target="_blank">#nameofqry.name#</a></li>
</cfoutput>
```